# Migration errors in cluster

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

After inserting a huge amount of documents to GridFs in MongoDB, two tables were not be able to return documents and next error has been popped up every few seconds:

```
Wed Aug 27 13:38:23.071 [conn25] about to log metadata event: { _id: "SERVER01-2
014-08-27T11:38:23-53fdc32fba9bd7afbc966714", server: "SERVER01", clientAddr: "1
0.10.10.10:64755", time: new Date(1409139503071), what: "moveChunk.from", ns: "l
ight.pdf.chunks", details: { min: { files_id: ObjectId('53f209895915c0643036e013
'), n: 0 }, max: { files_id: ObjectId('53f2098d5915c0643036e116'), n: 0 }, step1
of 6: 1, step2 of 6: 6, step3 of 6: 2, note: "aborted" } }
Wed Aug 27 13:38:23.071 [conn25] command admin.$cmd command: { moveChunk: "light
.pdf.chunks", from: "win/SERVER01:8771,SERVER02:8772", to: "nix/SERVER03:8773,SE
RVER04:8774", fromShard: "win", toShard: "nix", min: { files_id: ObjectId('53f20
9895915c0643036e013'), n: 0 }, max: { files_id: ObjectId('53f2098d5915c0643036e1
16'), n: 0 }, maxChunkSizeBytes: 67108864, shardId: "light.pdf.chunks-files_id_O
bjectId('53f209895915c0643036e013')n_0", configdb: "SERVER00:7770", secondaryThr
ottle: true, waitForDelete: false } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:183
r:410 reslen:463 231ms

Assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp 109
```

After this error I've tried to move PRIMARY machine with the given error to a SECONDARY using rs.stepDown(), and instance that was PRIMARY went down:

```
28T10:14:50.002+0200 [rsBackgroundSync] replSet syncing to: SERVER04:8774
2014-08-28T10:14:50.003+0200 [rsBackgroundSync] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to SERVER04:8774
2014-08-28T10:14:50.007+0200 [repl prefetch worker] uh oh: 6
2014-08-28T10:14:50.007+0200 [repl prefetch worker] light.pdf.chunks Assertion failure n >= 0 && n < static_cast<int>(_files.size()) src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp 109
2014-08-28T10:14:50.010+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.10.10.10:56424 #9 (7 connections now open)
2014-08-28T10:14:50.010+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.10.10.10:56425 #10 (8 connections now open)
2014-08-28T10:14:50.010+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.10.10.10:56426 #11 (9 connections now open)
2014-08-28T10:14:50.016+0200 [repl prefetch worker] light.pdf.chunks 0x11c0e91 0x1163109 0x1146f4e 0xee47e9 0xee4cad 0xb670f9 0xb5d1e9 0xb5d7c9 0xcfde57 0xcff573 0xe9e9b1 0x11569ae 0x1205829 0x7f0349357e9a 0x7f034866a3fd 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11c0e91]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x1163109]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x17e) [0x1146f4e]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13ExtentManager12_getOpenFileEi+0xc9) [0xee47e9]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13ExtentManager9recordForERKNS_7DiskLocE+0x1d) [0xee4cad]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo18BtreeInterfaceImplINS_12BtreeData_V1EE6locateEPKNS_17IndexCatalogEntryERKNS_7DiskLocERKNS_7BSONObjERiRbS8_i+0x39) [0xb670f9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22BtreeBasedAccessMethod5touchERKSt3setINS_7BSONObjENS_10BSONObjCmpESaIS2_EE+0x99) [0xb5d1e9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22BtreeBasedAccessMethod5touchERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x79) [0xb5d7c9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18prefetchIndexPagesEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x307) [0xcfde57]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo28prefetchPagesForReplicatedOpERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x713) [0xcff573]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset8SyncTail10prefetchOpERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x241) [0xe9e9b1]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x19e) [0x11569ae]
 mongod() [0x1205829]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7f0349357e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f034866a3fd]
2014-08-28T10:14:50.016+0200 [repl prefetch worker] uh oh: 5
2014-08-28T10:14:50.016+0200 [repl prefetch worker] light.pdf.chunks Assertion failure n >= 0 && n < static_cast<int>(_files.size()) src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp 109
2014-08-28T10:14:50.024+0200 [repl prefetch worker] light.pdf.chunks 0x11c0e91 0x1163109 0x1146f4e 0xee47e9 0xee4cad 0xb670f9 0xb5d1e9 0xb5d7c9 0xcfde57 0xcff573 0xe9e9b1 0x11569ae 0x1205829 0x7f0349357e9a 0x7f034866a3fd 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11c0e91]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x1163109]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x17e) [0x1146f4e]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13ExtentManager12_getOpenFileEi+0xc9) [0xee47e9]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13ExtentManager9recordForERKNS_7DiskLocE+0x1d) [0xee4cad]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo18BtreeInterfaceImplINS_12BtreeData_V1EE6locateEPKNS_17IndexCatalogEntryERKNS_7DiskLocERKNS_7BSONObjERiRbS8_i+0x39) [0xb670f9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22BtreeBasedAccessMethod5touchERKSt3setINS_7BSONObjENS_10BSONObjCmpESaIS2_EE+0x99) [0xb5d1e9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo22BtreeBasedAccessMethod5touchERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x79) [0xb5d7c9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo18prefetchIndexPagesEPNS_10CollectionERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x307) [0xcfde57]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo28prefetchPagesForReplicatedOpERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x713) [0xcff573]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset8SyncTail10prefetchOpERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x241) [0xe9e9b1]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x19e) [0x11569ae]
 mongod() [0x1205829]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7f0349357e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f034866a3fd]
2014-08-28T10:14:50.024+0200 [repl writer worker 1] uh oh: 6
2014-08-28T10:14:50.024+0200 [repl writer worker 1] light.pdf.chunks Assertion failure n >= 0 && n < static_cast<int>(_files.size()) src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp 109
2014-08-28T10:14:50.025+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.10.10.10:56427 #12 (10 connections now open)
2014-08-28T10:14:50.032+0200 [repl writer worker 1] light.pdf.chunks 0x11c0e91 0x1163109 0x1146f4e 0xee47e9 0xee4cad 0xb5cf2d 0xd21fdf 0xc3e009 0xc4a0f6 0xc39447 0xe3d225 0xe9f849 0xe9eef0 0x11569ae 0x1205829 0x7f0349357e9a 0x7f034866a3fd 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x11c0e91]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x1163109]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x17e) [0x1146f4e]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13ExtentManager12_getOpenFileEi+0xc9) [0xee47e9]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo13ExtentManager9recordForERKNS_7DiskLocE+0x1d) [0xee4cad]
 mongod(_ZNK5mongo22BtreeBasedAccessMethod10findSingleERKNS_7BSONObjE+0x4d) [0xb5cf2d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IDHackRunner7getNextEPNS_7BSONObjEPNS_7DiskLocE+0xbf) [0xd21fdf]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugEPNS_12UpdateDriverEPNS_14CanonicalQueryE+0x9c9) [0xc3e009]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14UpdateExecutor7executeEv+0x66) [0xc4a0f6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo6updateERKNS_13UpdateRequestEPNS_7OpDebugE+0x27) [0xc39447]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo21applyOperation_inlockERKNS_7BSONObjEbb+0xf25) [0xe3d225]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset8SyncTail9syncApplyERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0x749) [0xe9f849]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x50) [0xe9eef0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x19e) [0x11569ae]
 mongod() [0x1205829]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a) [0x7f0349357e9a]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f034866a3fd]
2014-08-28T10:14:50.033+0200 [repl writer worker 1] ERROR: writer worker caught exception:  :: caused by :: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp:109 on: { ts: Timestamp 1409213147000|3, h: 2971245438605874195, v: 2, op: "i", ns: "light.pdf.chunks", fromMigrate: true, o: { _id: ObjectId('53f2098b5915c0643036e07d'), files_id: ObjectId('53f2098b5915c0643036e079'), n: 1, data: BinData } }
2014-08-28T10:14:50.033+0200 [repl writer worker 1] Fatal Assertion 16360
2014-08-28T10:14:50.033+0200 [repl writer worker 1] 

***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Did someone meet the same problem?